# How to obtain the minimum point of the sum of a quadratic form and a L1 norm function?

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $u, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is a positive definite matrix.
The objective function is the sum of a quadratic form and a L1 norm:
$f(\gamma) = (\gamma-u)'W(\gamma-u) + \lambda\|\gamma\|_1$, where $(\cdot)'$ is the transpose of a matrix, the L1 norm is $\|\gamma\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |\gamma_i|$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is a known scalar.

My question is how to obtain the point $\gamma^{*}$ that $f(\gamma^{*})$ takes the minimum value.
Since the second part $\|\gamma\|_1$ is non-differentiable, I believe $\gamma^{*}(u)$ is a stepwise function.

If $W$ is an identity matrix, then we can have
$\gamma^{*}_i(u) = \max\{0, u_i - \frac{\lambda}{2}\} + 
\min\{0, u_i + \frac{\lambda}{2}\}$.
How about the expression of $\gamma^{*}(u)$ in the case where $W$ is no longer an identity matrix?

Comment: You could solve this optimization problem using an optimization algorithm such as the proximal gradient method or an accelerated proximal gradient method (FISTA, for example). You can search for how to solve a Lasso problem using the proximal gradient method to learn how it works.

Comment: Thanks. I also wonder that is it possible to obtain a explicit expression for $\gamma^{*}(v)$. I can find some results if $W$ is an identity matrix, but it seems complicated if $W$ is fully populated.

Comment: I was a little confused. I see now that if $W$ is an identity matrix then we’re evaluating the proximal operator of the $\ell_1$-norm, which does have a closed form expression.

Comment: What is the $v$ in $\gamma^*(v)$?

Comment: Sorry, I have re-edited the question. I have no idea to obtain the closed form expression of $\gamma^{*}$ with a general $W$.

Comment: It is only possible to obtain the explicit formula in the case when $W$ is identity or diagonal (and pos. deifinite) because in this case both the quadratic and $\ell_1$ terms are separable (sums of of functions of each coordinate).  These 1D problems can be solved independently.  In the general case, this does not work and you need to solve the problem numerically.